# Is There any android Emulator that have Sim slot but no sim in?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-emulator, simulator

I want to Remove insert Sim in android emulator but i cannot see any setting their how i can achive it or is there any specific model here in which we can insert remove sim card..?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to menu options as shown in below image,

[image]

And then,

Change whichever setting you want from Cellular menu

[image]

Comment: Karan i know this setting but the question is that i want to remove sim from emulator like emulator has slot like real device but no sim in it

Comment: There is voice status and data status in which you can change that to "Unregistered"